# How to do linear interpolation between two points with n-dimensions?

Tags: geometry

say there are two points P1 and P2 in $R^n$. 
P1 = (i1, j1, k1, l1, m1, ... )     [n dimensions]
P2 = (i2, j2, k2, l2, m2, ... )     [n dimensions]

How do I get the interpolated n-dim points between them?

Comment: If "interpolate" means you want points on the straight line connecting $P_1$ and $P_2,$ you can generalize the method in [Using linear interpolation between two points to find the three remaining points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1177149/139123) from two dimensions to $n$ dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can linearly interpolate just like in one dimension:

$$
P_\lambda = P_1 + \lambda (P_2 - P_1),
$$
for $\lambda\in [0,1]$, will give you points on the line segment connecting $P_1$ and $P_2$.